# How do i plot a piechart and barchart in R programming for a data frame with the variables for this given data?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

```
No.of Litecoin  No. of bitcoin
        0            5
        1            1
        3            0
        0            0
        0            3
        3            1
        0            0
```

I need to plot a piechart and a bar chart that shows the given variable and it's frequency.

I know this looks simple to many of you but it would mean a lot to a beginner like me

Comment: It's much better for learning if you showed what you tried. Have you looked at any tutorials? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Please provide more information. For instance, what programming language or technology are you using? How are you getting the datas? Do you have any examples of your program script that you could provide?

Comment: Hi, i got stuck at here https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM4QT.png
In this tutorial(the picture in the link), the variable is on the left side of the dataframe. In my situation now, the variable is on the top side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 examples of solutions :

```
out <- data.frame(my_col = c("One", "One", "Two", "Two", "Others"))

#Transform data 
df <- data.frame(table(out$my_col)) 
names(df) <- c("label", "value")

#Plot with R-base 
pie(df$value, df$label) 
barplot(value~label, df)

#Plot with package 
library(rAmCharts) 
amPie(df) 
amBarplot( "label", "value", df)
```

For more examples you can go on [Graphs gallery](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/)